How to get wallet Total Token Balance (in USD)
si there any api to detect whale according to estimated USD token balance he has? (in solscan you can see Total Balance and ($ estimated sum it has), ideally is to get  just this  $ estimated sum

Solscan might have an API that you can use to estimate a wallet's balance. Otherwise, it's a hard problem because you need to fetch a price for each token type in a wallet.
